# react native how to deal with Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined

I'm expecting some data from remote server to show it in the screen but I got this error in the simulator `Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` the reason why is the content is rendered before the arrival of the results, this the part of code where I'm having this error :

```
caption = { this.state.customFieldDropdown['gender'][this.state.dropDownSelectedItems['gender'] ] || '---Choose---' }
```

So the property `caption` is expecting a text, and to deal with undefined values I added this  `|| '---Choose---'` to show text `'---Choose---'` in case of null but the problem is `this.state.dropDownSelectedItems['gender']` is undefined and when `this.state.customFieldDropdown` access that value it caused the error ( reading property which is undefined)

So how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have undefined value higher in the property chain. The `||` operator will match only last value in the chain, so if for example `this.state.customFieldDropdown['gender']` is undefined it will fail.

I'll suggest you to take a look at idx function introduced by React team. More details here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/idx-the-existential-function.html

Answer (score 0):

Idx is really good. You can do something like that:

```
if (idx(this.state, _ => _.customFieldDropdown.gender[_.dropDownSelectedItems.gender]))
    caption = this.state.customFieldDropdown.gender[this.state.dropDownSelectedItems.gender]
else
    caption = '---Choose---'
```